# Sharepoint 2010 Standalone mode not hooked up to AD

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I have installed sharepoint 2010 in standalone mode. the only user it is seeing is the user I created the account with. How can I point it to AD to see other users? this is a test server on our network as sharepoint is installed else where. We are using NTLM as the authenication method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not join the machine to the domain?  You would have had to do some workarounds to install it without AD?

If this is the case, I'm not sure you can point it back to another AD directly.  You could implement a federation scenario with AD FS and consume it, or FBA w/LDAP.

If the standalone is it's own domain, and you want to connect to another it isn't difficult to configure a one way trust and allow authentication that way.

Outside of those, I would rebuild the box and be sure it is connected to your test AD environment initially.